# Pass variable to a component

Tags: angular, tinymce

I'm trying to pass a variable *commentEdit* from `viewbook.component.ts` to `tinymce.component.ts`, but it receives a wrong value.

The problem is that "comment" in `tinymce.component.ts` always receives an empty string ' '.

When I do click on the *span*, commentEdit gets a new value, but it dont update the value on the other component.

How can I do that?

**viewbook.component.ts**

```
...
export class ViewBookComponent implements OnInit {
    public commentEdit= '';
    public comment='';
    ...
    keyupHandlerFunction(bookComment) {
        this.comment = bookComment;
    } 

    openModalEdit(comment) {
        this.commentEdit = comment;
    }
    ...
}
```

**viewbook.component.html**

```
...
<span (click)="openModalEdit(comment.comment)" data-toggle="modal"...></span>
...
<tinymce
    [elementId]="'edit-comment-book'"
    [plugins]="['link', 'paste']"
    [comment]='commentEdit'
    (onEditorKeyup)="keyupHandlerFunction($event)"
>
</tinymce>
...
```

**tinymce.component.ts**

```
export class TinymceComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
    @Input() comment: String;
    ...
```

Thanks!

Edit: I have solved it using ngOnChanges() [Tinymce Angular 2 integration : how to set the content of the editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42412981/tinymce-angular-2-integration-how-to-set-the-content-of-the-editor)

Comment: Have you logged comment.comment value? How do you get it ? is it an input enter?

Comment: "<div *ngFor="let comment of comments..." the span is inside, so there are some spans. I put a console.log() inside openModalEdit() and the value is right there

Comment: This one, simplified, works : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iry36z?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: I tried with <h1></h1> and it works properly. My problem was  with tinymce but I have solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to access the value on html template , trying using getter and setter . Can provide more info if needed.

Comment: If I declare "public commentEdit=' ';" as "public commentEdit='example'"; It always receives "example" in the other component, so I think that the problem is not on the way that I access to the variable. Edit: Just in case, I have tried with an getter( ) method, and I still have the same problem :(

Comment: can u please provide a plunker?